Wave equation with periodic boundary values - D.Alembert's solution vs separation of variables.
The D.Alembert's solution  to the initial value problem
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}, \quad u(0, x) = f(x), \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(0, x) = g(x),
$$
is given by
$$
u(t, x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(f(x - c t) + f(x + c t)\right) + \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} g(z) dz,
$$
for $-\infty < x < \infty$, where
On the other hand using separation of variables I can solve the same problem but with periodic boundary conditions $ u(t,-\pi) = u(t,\pi), \quad u_t(t,-\pi) = u_t(\pi)$ and have:
\begin{align*}
 u(t, x) &= \frac{1}{2}a_0 + \frac{1}{2}c_0 t \\
 &\quad + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg( a_n \cos{(nct)} \cos{(nx)} + b_n \cos{(nct)} \sin{(nx)} \\
 &\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad+ \frac{c_n}{nc} \sin{(nct)} \cos{(nx)} + \frac{d_n}{nc} \sin{(nct)} \sin{(nx)} \Bigg),
\end{align*}
where $a_n$, $b_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$, while $c_n$, $d_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $g(x)$.
Now I want to use the D.Alembert's solution
to solve the boundary value problem and compare the solution with solution of the method of separation of variables.  My thinking was to periodically extend $f(x), g(x)$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$ and use the D.Alembert's formula.
Will that work ? Will this D.Alembert's solution be identical to the solution of the method of separation of variables ?
